# FFT Fundamental frequency calculation from LomontFFT

Tags: c#, algorithm, signal-processing, fft

I am using the LomontFFT from http://www.lomont.org/Software/Misc/FFT/LomontFFT.html to get the fundamental frequency from sampled values of a signal. For testing if the fundamental frequency is correctly determined, I have used some samples from past (with known fundamental frequency).

Below is the code I have written to call the LomontFFT algo and determine the FFT:

```
private void buttonFFT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //double fftavg = 0;
        double fftmax = 0;
        var fftData = new byte[512];
        double[] fftValues = Enumerable.Repeat(0.0, 512).ToArray();

                           Array.Copy(sapmledDoubleValuesADC1, fftValues, sapmledDoubleValuesADC1.Length);
var fftMethod = new Lomont.LomontFFT();
        fftMethod.RealFFT(fftValues, true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 512; i += 2)
        {
            double fftmag = Math.Sqrt((fftValues[i] * fftValues[i]) + (fftValues[i + 1] * fftValues[i + 1]));
            if (fftmag > fftmax)
                fftmax = fftmag;
            //fftavg += fftmag;
            //fftData[i] = (byte)fftmag;
            //fftData[i + 1] = fftData[i];
        }
        textBoxFundaFreq.Text = "Frey = " + fftmax.ToString();
        for (int x = 1; x < 512; x++)
        {
            this.chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, fftValues[x]);
        }
    }
```

But the problem is the magnitude of the frequency is wrong. The FFT also doesn't match but that is possible as there are multiple solutions, but the frequency should be same. The algo is proven for many years so its definitely not wrong. Am I doing something wrong in calling code?

(I have only real values in sampled data)

Comment: please reformat the code

Comment: Sorry, the spaces went wrong from my phone and unformatted code. But its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental frequency extraction / pitch detection is *not* a simple algorithm. For most input signal (anything other than a single sine/cosine wave) the FFT will show several peaks and it is usually better to estimate the *distance* between this peaks.

Further you need to interpolate the FFT bins to get an acurate result for a single peak.

For most applications it is better to calculate the auto-correlation-function (ACF) anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But the higjest magnitude in the value series should represent the fundamental frequency, if not exact I should get something near. The algorithm for fft is also from a very standard one.

Comment: wrong! Add 0.5*100Hz + 0.9*200Hz + 1.5*300Hz. Pitch = 100 Hz, Highest component = 300 Hz.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is it possible to explain it a little bit. Is the  pitch fixed to 100Hz for any kind of signal? And how is the factor 05,0.9 and 1.5 obtained?

Comment: This was an example. If you have a signal which consists of several components like described, you'll find a pitch of 100Hz and a largest FFT component of 300Hz. It is even possible to have a signal with a pitch of 100Hz and *no 100Hz component at all*